# Why does an empty 'for' loop run slower than another 'for' loop which has code in it?

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop

Something made me crazy. I am generating almost all the integers in a `for loop` and measure the running time. But, I have faced a problem. Please have a look at these two codes:

first:

```
unsigned long x = 0;
unsigned int t = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
    x++;
}

cout << x << endl << t;
```

second:

```
unsigned long x = 0;
unsigned int t = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
    // Do nothing
}

cout << x << endl << t;
```

The only difference is removing `x++` from the first `for` loop. I expected that an empty `for` loop would have less running time compared to another loop which is changing the variable `x` in memory. However, the first one took about 7 secs on my system, and the second one took 8.5 secs. I am using these codes for measuring time:

```
auto a = chrono::steady_clock::now();

// code

auto b = chrono::steady_clock::now();
double time = chrono::duration <double, milli> (b - a).count();
cout << endl << "time ---> " << time * 0.001 << " sec";
```

How can this be?

Comment: Have you looked at the generated assembly code? Are you sure that the compiler doesn't optimize away the empty line?

Comment: Benchmarks on unoptimized compilations is a waste of time.

Comment: Try reversing the order of the assessment.  You may have cache artifacts.  Post true assessment code.

Comment: At what [optimization level](https://godbolt.org/z/8Gnxfh85a) (note the warnings) have you compiled this?

Comment: How many times did you measure? By the way, comparing signed with unsigned int is avoidable

Comment: By the way, when I say "empty line" I of course mean "empty *loop*" :)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.

Comment: Benchmarking a block of code 1 time can have anomalous results.  Run the same block over and over and see what the benchmark says over, say, 1000 runs.